# Executing Query String in Wordpress without refresh

Tags: jquery, wordpress, query-string, woocommerce

I have found the following code to empty my cart on wordpress/woocommerce.

```
add_action('init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url');
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
    global $woocommerce;
    if( isset($_REQUEST['clear-cart']) ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    }
}
```

To execute this I add ?clear-cart to any URL on my site, I'm a little over my head here.

But I was wondering if there was a way using jQuery or something to execute this function without a page refresh?

Comment: you need to use ajax in order to make server request without reloading page

Comment: What would be the simplest AJAX to write just to fire that function?

Comment: I don't know wordpress so i won't can help you on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the URL for clearing your cart is `host/cart/clear`

You can access that URL by sending an [AJAX POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) request to the server:

`var request = $.post('host/cart/clear');`

If you want to attach event handlers for the sucess and/or failure of the [request](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise):

```
request.done(successHandler);
request.fail(failureHandler);
```

Where success- and failureHandler are functions.